# OOP efficiency when using a class in another class

Tags: php, class, oop, pdo

I have a class called DB (class.pdo.php) that does all the handling on mysql queries using PDO and another class called user that I use to manage a login system.

My question relates to always having to instantiate the $db in every public function of users so I can use DB. Is this efficient? Shouldn't I be instantiating DB inside the __construct() of users?

This is my code

```
 require_once("../../class.pdo.php");

class user {

private $db = null;

public function __construct(){
    /* Empty? */
}

public function find_by_email($email){
    $db = new db();
    $db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1');
    $db->bind(':email',$email);
    $result = $db->single();
    return $result;
}

public function create($email,$password,$first_name,$last_name){ 
    $db = new db();
    $db->query("INSERT INTO users(email,password,first_name,last_name,created_at) VALUES (:email,:password,:first_name,:last_name,NOW())");
    $db->bind(':email',$email);
    $db->bind(':password',$password);
    $db->bind(':first_name',$first_name);
    $db->bind(':last_name',$last_name);
    $result = $db->execute();
    return $db->lastInsertId();
}

 [more similar functions ommited]
```

Comment: How do you define "efficient" term? How do you measure "efficiency"?

Comment: Instantiate it once, and use dependency injection to pass it to all the classe that need it

Comment: What is the difference between your class and PDO?

Comment: It's most likely inefficient. It's also not good from a software engineering perspective: your class (its methods) depend on the existence of `db` but do not advertise this anywhere; it's only visible if you read the method implementations.

Comment: When I write efficient I mean resources consumed on server side... I'd love to have the code as good and efficient as possible. I'm all for good practices and I'm still quite confused with many oop details.

Comment: class.users.php has about 7 or 8 functions and all instantiate $db... seems odd to me but I'm the noob here.

Comment: Aim for good coding practice before worrying about server efficiency. For the most part, if good coding practice is efficient. Where it isn't efficient, it is that way for good reasons.

Comment: @Spudley: And what I'm doing here is good practice? That's one of my major worries... I want to be as good as possible from the get go.

Comment: @Afonso Gomes: there are dozens of various resources that server provides and consumes. And you cannot optimize usage of all of them. Every optimization for resource A cost some units of resource B.

Comment: You have a private `$db` property, but you're never using it; you're creating a new local `$db` in every method. That's not good. Create the DB object once and use it across the class. Also, as others have said, it would be even better to pass the DB object into the class, rather than creating it inside the class. This is called 'Dependency Injection'. It's a big topic, so I won't go into detail here, but google will give you plenty to read.

Comment: @zerkms: I know bro. I just don't want to do something that melts it down :) I'm new to OOP and still lack a good grasp of it, so I don't have a clue if it's a good practice or efficient to always instantiate DB in every single method of Users.

Comment: @Spudley: That's what I needed to hear. will google for dependency injection. heard it before but dint't know the use of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using the Singleton pattern to create one object for the connection and use it everytime you need it, instead of creating new objects all the time?

Comment: Singleton is more an anti-pattern than a pattern. Singletons should not be used by database connectors because NOT ALWAYS you'll just one connection to just one database.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos what prevents you from using singleton with default connection but creating another instance when provided with  different credentials?

Comment: If you do not INJECT the singleton, you cannot change it. If you just do: `public function someMethod() { DbConnector::getInstance()->query(...); }` you'll never be able to change the connector.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos so, it is not a singleton itself but implementation. though anyway, you could always do something like `DbConnector::getInstance('another')->query(...)`. Everything is possible.

Comment: Well, this is a (Singleton) Registry, not a Singleton anymore. It make things a little bit better. I'd have to elaborate a little more to explain why is bad using global state patterns, such as Singleton and Registry, but it is a valid solution.

Answer (score 3):

Well, despite of some comments suggesting the use of the Singleton pattern, I totaly disagree in using it for this purpose.

Your application will not always use a single connection to just one database.

Let me show you how I'd do this:

```
class DbConnector {
    private $dbh;
    private $dsn;

    public function __construct($dsn) {
        $this->dsn = $dsn;
    }

    private function connect() {
        if($this->dbh === null) {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($this->dsn);
        }
    }

    public function disconnect {
        if($this->dbh !== null) {
            $this->dbh = null;
        }
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        $this->connect();
        //... do the rest
    }

    public function fetchAll($sql) {
        $this->connect();
        //... do the rest
    }

    public function insert($table, $values) {
        $this->connect();
        //... do the rest
    }

    public function update($table, $values, $cond) {
        $this->connect();
        //... do the rest
    }

    public function delete($table, $cond) {
        $this->connect();
        //... do the rest
    }
}

class User {
    private $dbConn;
    public function __construct(DbConnector $dbConn) {
        $this->dbConn = $dbConn;
    }

    public function create($email,$password,$first_name,$last_name){ 
        $this->dbConn->query("INSERT INTO users(email,password,first_name,last_name,created_at VALUES (:email,:password,:first_name,:last_name,NOW())");
        $this->dbConn->bind(':email',$email);
        $this->dbConn->bind(':password',$email);
        $this->dbConn->bind(':first_name',$email);
        $this->dbConn->bind(':last_name',$email);
        $this->dbConn->execute();
        return $this->dbConn->lastInsertId();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Results:

- No singleton used = testable.
- Connection to the database is just openned when needed
- Your connection is persistent. If you open and close connections in every method, you loose the capability of creating transactions.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something similar with lazy loading: don't initiate in the constructor unless you're sure you actually need the connection every time an object is created but absolutly don't create a new object on each method call. Instead, save the resulting object into an object var which is checked on each method call and initiates the connection if missing.

```
class user {
  protected $_db = null;
  private function _init_db() { $this->_db = new XXX; }
  public function create( $x, $y, $z ) {
    if ( ! $this->_db ) $this->_init_db();
    # use $this->_db ..
  }
  public function find_by_email( $x, $y, $z ) {
    if ( ! $this->_db ) $this->_init_db();
    # etc
  }
}
```

This has the advantages of avoiding global static state (singletons..) and only creates the connection / object at the very last moment so you're sure you actually need it and it's not just a useless connection.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of efficiency, the main problem with your code is that it establishes **new connection** for the every method called. This one is indeed **inefficient to the point of killing your database server**. And it's incomparable to the other problem you have.

So, in general, you can have whatever way you want - either get somehow an instance of db class in the every function or use a class variable - but either way have to use **single PDO instance throughout whole application**.

Also I find your functions quite inefficient from the amount of code point of view, and would have optimized them this way

```
public function create($email,$password,$first_name,$last_name){ 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(email,password,first_name,last_name,created_at) VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW())";
    $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $db->execute(func_get_args());
    return $db->lastInsertId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a object point of view, I'd leave database instantiating within the methods, rather than an entire class.

Each method should only see the variables and data it needs, in order to perform its function.
For instance, a `createUser()` method would need to see variables or properties such as `$username`, `$usergroupId`, as well as `$database` etc.

However, you may have a function which is called `randomPassword()`, which generates a random password from numbers and letter.

This randomPassword() function doesn't need the database object and therefore, an already initialised database connection in the object scope would be wasteful.

It would be better only to create the new database object in methods that required it.

In addition, in my application, I don't create a new database connection each time I used `new database`. Instead, I've opted for a singleton PDO database object which keeps the connection active.

I can then just call the database object statically to retrieve an existing connection. Therefore, if, in the process of running my application I need to have 20 database objects, my application then only returns the same object, and the same connection.

Comment: I disagree with creating one connect per method, because this way there's no persistency in the information from database. Connectors should be created before and passed to the object. Each method could be responsible by call a method like `connect` in DB class, because you don't need connect immediatly when you create an DB object. This is called Lazy Initialization.

Comment: I agree @henriques Barcelos, I did add that instead of creating a new object per method, that I personally have a singleton PDO which I just import into each method that requires it :)

Comment: So ... you're saying i'm in the right track? I have this try{$this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);} in the __construct of the class db

Comment: Singleton is also a problem. How can you unit test these classes using a singleton?

Comment: Singletons may cause problems with unit testing, however is it more efficient to open 10 connections per application run, or when appropriate, 1 reusable connection? Why not incorporate a parent factory pattern to return a singleton object on normal request, but a new connection when required?

Comment: It's just NOT create a connection everytime you need to perform a query. See my answer.